# PyQt Set Row Height Creates A Large Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

In PyQt I am trying to create a QTableWidget. It all works perfectly. However, when I try to resize the rows, all of the rows are resized, except from the last one. I don't want to use setMaximumHeight because the number of rows may vary.

This is my code:

```py
self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()

self.table.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.table.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
self.table.setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);border-width: 0px; border-style: solid")
self.table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("::section{Background-color:rgb(240, 240, 240); border: none; height: 70px}")
self.table.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

self.table.setColumnCount(3)
self.table.setRowCount(7)

self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
self.table.setShowGrid(False)
self.table.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
self.table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.table.setMinimumWidth(690)

self.horizontalHeader = self.table.horizontalHeader()
self.horizontalHeader.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
self.horizontalHeader.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
self.horizontalHeader.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
self.horizontalHeader.setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
self.horizontalHeader.setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)

self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("Deck;Due;New").split(";"))

self.tableHeaderFont = self.table.horizontalHeader().font()
self.tableHeaderFont.setPointSize(10)
self.tableHeaderFont.setBold(True)
self.tableHeaderFont.setWeight(75)
self.table.horizontalHeader().setFont(self.tableHeaderFont)

self.verticalHeader = self.table.verticalHeader()
self.verticalHeader.setMinimumSectionSize(30)

for section in range(self.verticalHeader.count()):
    self.verticalHeader.resizeSection(section, 30)
```

This is the result I get

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting a size policy at the top. This is what I did:

```py
self.table.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
```

The total code would look like:

```py
self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()

self.table.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)

self.table.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.table.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
self.table.setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);border-width: 0px; border-style: solid")
self.table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("::section{Background-color:rgb(240, 240, 240); border: none; height: 70px}")
self.table.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

self.table.setColumnCount(3)
self.table.setRowCount(7)

self.verticalHeader = self.table.verticalHeader()
self.verticalHeader.setMinimumSectionSize(30)
self.table.resizeRowsToContents()

for section in range(self.verticalHeader.count()):
    self.verticalHeader.resizeSection(section, 30)

self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
self.table.setShowGrid(False)
self.table.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
self.table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.table.setMinimumWidth(690)

self.horizontalHeader = self.table.horizontalHeader()
self.horizontalHeader.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
self.horizontalHeader.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
self.horizontalHeader.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
self.horizontalHeader.setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
self.horizontalHeader.setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)

self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("Name;Place;New").split(";"))

self.tableHeaderFont = self.table.horizontalHeader().font()
self.tableHeaderFont.setPointSize(10)
self.tableHeaderFont.setBold(True)
self.tableHeaderFont.setWeight(75)
self.table.horizontalHeader().setFont(self.tableHeaderFont)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped. I've been working on this all day!

Comment: What has the size policy to do with that? The problem is about the size hint (which does *not* consider the contents of the table). Also, setting the policy to `Minimum` doesn't prevent expansion of the widget, if other widgets in the layout have maximum sizes (or `Minimum` policy) set for that direction.

Comment: I was just playing around a bit and managed to fix this by setting the size policy to minimum. I would love to see your idea though!

Comment: How would you use size hint?